# Stored Functions with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities, stored-functions

How can I make a MS-SQL stored function availabe in LINQ expressions if using the Entity framework?

The SQL function was created with `CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@name) ...`). I was hoping to access it similarly to this:

```
var data = from c in entities.Users where MyFunction(c.name) = 3;
```

Unfortunately I have only .NET 3.5 available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can [import DB functions in EF 1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/01/defining-custom-functions-in-entity-framework.aspx). But you don't get `EdmFunctionAttribute` in EF 1, so you're limited to the contexts where you can use them. You need EF 4 for that.

For your case you might want to consider mapping a proc returning `Users` (for 3.5; again, 4 is better for this feature).